# Notes Clients losing connections

Tags: windows, lotus-notes

I have some Lotus Notes clients that looses server connection. They suddenly get "server not responding".
If you "OK" that dialog and try to click on another database the message shows again.
Open database don't work either, not even with ip.

But if you go into preference and notes ports and trace write the same server name and hit trace. The server is found and you can exit preference and everything work ok again.

I have also tried to add the server with a connection document.

Clients is 8.5.2 and 8.5.3 windows 7 and windows vista

Anybody seen this before / have a solution?

Comment: my guess is that maybe they are timing out due to latency. is there a timeout setting you can increase?

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault instead of StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, probably. Actually I didn't know that side existed until now. :-)

Comment: Is your Notes data directory on a network drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus notes looks at DNS firstly. Can you check that?

Open a command prompt, try to ping the server name (if your server is SomeServer/SomeOU/Company then you would try pinging SomeServer). It's important if it resolves the right IP address.

Disable any firewall in case.

Look for any invalid additional connection documents and default passthru server setting in location document.

Also, since you mentioned Vista and Win7, I suspect if it might be an IPv6 issue. Disable IPV6 from server and clients to eliminate this option.

Finally, can you check the local notes log for any extraordinary message about the connection attempt?

Comment: If it doesn't find the server in the dns, does the connections docs decide then?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But if it resolves as wrong IP, that could be the problem.

Comment: The problem probably has to do with some config of the DNS server because sometimes it accepts a name without the AD Domain and sometimes not.

Comment: My best practice is to keep the server computer name same as the domino server common name. If server is included in AD domain, it resolves automatically. But AD sucks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. What I found was that by default, Notes creates a connection document in the personal address book (Contacts) with a priority of "Low". However, when the client tries to resolve the address it only checks "Normal" priority conenction docs. So it never finds the connection. Verify there is a connection doc to the server with a priority of Normal. You might want to put the explict ip address in the connection doc also, just to bypass the DNS for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use IP address instead of server name. It works for me almost every time.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the tcpip connection time to 30 seconds from 5 at the lotus client or domino admin client server setup in configuration.